# Custom slide left view transition

Tags: iphone, uiview, transition, slide

I am trying to do a simple view transition when swiping gesture is recognized;
I am absolute beginner to both objective C and iOs and I am really strugelling with the semantics.

i am using this:

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view2 cache:YES];
```

I have a view controller with a default view and 2 other views(view1 and view2) which are inserted as subviews to self.view when the default view loads(if(viewDidLoad))

I am trying to get 6 different views and be able to swipe left and right to next and respectively previous views. (similar to some image galleries)
as in default view is view1 swipe left go to view2.

what I have so far works fine but I am restricted by the 4 types of standard transitions Curl up/down and Flip left/right.

I need a transition slide Left/right to replace my current one. 
How do I define a new one?
Do I need CG framework, or can I het away without using it?

Can I just do smth like

```
transition ***myTransition**
{
define transition
}

[UIView setAnimationTransition: **myTransition** forView:self.view2 cache:YES];
```

thank you!

Comment: I managed to do it usig CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation) works like a charm ^^

Answer (score 0):

Read UIView and CAAnimation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Introduction/Introduction.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html
You can use other animation types as given here